# How to solve contradiction in Coq

Tags: coq

I have statement  `true <> false`, in hypothesis. I want to prove
`true = false`. Can I solve it? The problem is that, it can not be solved by contradiction.

Comment: There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show what you have tried so far. You will see that you will get better answers (and upvotes) to your question if you provide all *relevant* information.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should provide a better example. That said! You need to be clear...is `true <> false` above the line (eg a hypothesis) or below the line (a goal)?

I'm assuming it is a goal, because as a hypothesis, it doesn't actually tell you anything (it's just a tautology).

If it's a goal:

```
Goal (true <> false)
intros contra; discriminate.
```

There are a lot of general ways to deal with contradictions..discriminate and inversion are quite common. But a clearer example would be better.

Something to note in general is that `A <> B` is just a notation for `A=B->False`, which is why "intros contra" above works, because it's pulling out the hypothesis. In cases where you're not sure what to do, you can use intros to put the equality above the line and then derive a contradiction.

In the case where you have something like `true <> true` *above* the line (that's important), then you can apply it.

Example

```
Goal (true <> true -> 0 = 1).                                                                   
intros contra.
exfalso.
apply contra.
reflexivity.
```

`exfalso` clears out the current goal and replaces it with False -- this is useful when you have an impossible goal but a contradiction in your hypothesis (above the line). `apply contra` uses the fact that <> is ->False like I mentioned above.

Comment: Theorem Sa_true :forall (b a:nat),
((b - b)=? 0)=true ->
((b - b)=? (S a))=true.

While proving lemma, I get true=false in goal and true <> false 
in hypothesis(above line).How to close this?

Comment: If `true<>false` is above the line then it isn't giving you anything. It's a tautology that you can't do anything with. You have a false goal, and a tautology above the line...so your proof has gone wrong somewhere. Furthermore,  I don't think your proof is true?the hypothesis is always true: b-b=0 is always true and doesn't really tell you anything. And it certainly is not the case that b-b=S a, because that's saying that S a=0 forall a...in fact, that is never true! I think you may be expressing the theorem you want to prove incorrectly?

Comment: Theorem Sa_false :forall (b a:nat),
((b - b)=? 0)=true ->
((b - b)=? (S a))=false .This is true statement,I have proved it.But during destruct command I  come across above lemma.I have tried negation of expression(((b - b)=? (S a))=false) and proved it.But don't know ,how these two lemmas can help me in closing first lemma,which I have asked.